# MVVM - How do I open a window based on a selected item from a list?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am quite new to the WPF & MVVM world, and have spent the last few days downloading as many tutorials as I could, and reading as much as possible!

I am however struggling to implement with a very basic and common concept with MVVM and am desperate for some help - and perhaps even an example :-)

I've got the basics of M-V-VM, commanding, and even messenging; but how on earch do I open a new window and set that windows ViewModel to the selected item of a listbox?

Let me explain:
I have a Model called Client and it has some properties
I then have a ViewModel which gets all my Clients and stores them in an ObservableCollection
I have a screen where I display the Name & Surname in a listbox and allow the user to filter and search.

All of the above work perfectly.

When a user selects an item though, I would like to open an editable "detailed client view" screen of that particular client.  This detailed screen's ViewModel would need to somehow bind to the selected item (if that makes sense); or I need to be able to pass a paramter to the newly opened screen's ViewModel.  In fact, if the user could open several detail screens at the same time and edit multiple clints it would be great!

If anyone can give me a nice example, or point me in the right direction I would truly be greatful!

Many thanks,
Brendan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an event to the ListBox.SelectionChanged which does the following:

- Creates a new Dialog and DialogViewModel
- Binds the DialogViewModel.EditableContentProperty to the ListBox's SelectedItem
- Dialog.DataContext = DialogViewModel
- Dialog.ShowDialog()

Comment: Thanks Rachel, I have kind of come right.  I have created a constructor for my DetailViewModel and have bound it to the DetailForms datacontext in the code-behind of the listview double click.  I clearly hadn't "clicked" that one can create and bind viewmodels in code like that...

Comment: You really shouldn't do this, unless your dialog is trivial enough that it would be a waste of code to create a dialog view model. Ideally all your presentation logic is in view models, including navigation such as spinning up new views and view models.

Comment: Even if you wanted to do it completely in ViewModels, I would do it in a similar fashion. Main difference would be the ListBox.SelectionChanged would point to a ViewModel Command and the code would be in the VM instead of the code behind.

Comment: If one opens a Window / form from within a ViewModel, can one set the Owner property?  And to what?  I have some code that uses the "this.OwnedWindows" to activate windows under certain circumstances.

Comment: I have a similar situation where the user clicks an edit button on a grid row. This invokes the `EditRow` command on the grid view model, which creates a new edit dialogue, and passes it the row view model in it's constructor. It doesn't need a parameterless constructor, because I can pass null and create a new details view model if the parameter is null.

Comment: Is there any examples where we can see this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put:

```
//Create the Client Detail form
frmClientDetails frm = new frmClientDetails();
frm.Owner = this;
var ViewModel = new ClientDetailViewModel((Client)lstFoundClients.Items.CurrentItem);
frm.DataContext = ViewModel;
frm.Show();
```